# Getting Python variable name or value from memory location?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I have looked around the forums and I can't seem to find an answer (and there might not be one actually) as to whether or not you can get the name of a variable or the value by using its memory location in Python.  In other words, when I declare `a = 10` and assign the value `10` to the variable `'a'`, and then I use the `id()` function on `'a'` I get the location in memory where the value for `'a'` is stored.  Is there a way to, say, print the variable name `('a')` or the value `('10')` by referencing the value that `id()` returns (either the decimal value or converting the decimal value to hex with the `hex()` function)?  I tried a few things like `print(id(variable-name))` and just `print(decimal-value-from-id)` and no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: No.  In fact, `id(obj)` being the location in memory of `obj` is a CPython implementation detail, and shouldn't be relied upon

Comment: You could probably do this in a C extension, but not pure python

Comment: Well you could store a dictionary of id values to variables, and intern your strings to ensure this is applied consistently, but what is your ultimate aim here?

Comment: Even though this is possible in CPython, it is highly inadvisable for you to rely on this. Also, it is important to note that the value returned by `id` isn't linked to the variable, but the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html):

```
import ctypes
a = 10
ctypes.cast(id(a), ctypes.py_object).value
#10
```

This will, of course, work if the object is still there.

Comment: I am very tempted to downvote this... You can guarantee that it only exists if *you* are holding a reference to that variable, in which case you could actually store it somewhere indexable with the ID.

Comment: Your concerns are in place and I wouldn't suggest this in production. Still, it is what OP wanted to do.

Comment: Zipa, thank you for your reply and this is what I was looking for.  The reason I posted was that I was having a conversation about mutable vs. immutable and used the id() function to show that mutable objects like lists can be changed in place (where id() returns the same memory value/location) and an integer or string variable name returns a new id() value when changed (so can't be changed in place). Was asked how I could take the memory location value generated by id() to get the name or value of the variable stored at that location - kinda reverse engineer it so to speak.  Thank you!!